# Можно ли сделать так что-бы между сценами играла не прерывно музыка[Unity]

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Мне нужно что-бы на 1 и во 2 сцене играла одна музыка и при переходе не прерывалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Самая** правильная реализации - это реализация через `DontDestroyOnLoad`

Так-же, на русскоязычном Ютубе уже есть урок по `DontDestroyOnLoad`, там как раз, делают бесшовную музыку при переходе между сценами, посмотреть ролик можно [тут](https://youtu.be/j38d_gkClLA)

Answer (score 2):

[Форум.](https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2501570.html)
При переходе, объект не удаляется и музыка продолжает играть

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 
public class ExampleCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }
 
    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        if (scene.name == "3")
            audio.mute = true;
        else
            audio.mute = false;
    }
 
    void Destroy()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }
}
```

Comment: `audio.mute = scene.name == "3";` :)